# segmentation fault on trying to copy the shared memory address

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    /* Initialise the variables */
    int key,shmid,fd1,bytes_written;
    char *shmptr = NULL;
    char *buff = NULL;
    key = shmid = fd1 = bytes_written = 0;

    /*Validate the i/p parameter*/
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Enter the Output file");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\n The Output File is : %s \n",argv[1]);

    /* Open the file in write mode */
    fd1 = open(argv[1],O_WRONLY);
    if(fd1 == -1){
        printf("\n File cannot be opened!  \n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create the shared memory key */
    key = ftok(".",12);

    /* create the shared memory segment */
    shmid = shmget(key,1000,0);

    /* Attach with the shared memory segment
    ** get the pointer to the shared address
    */
#if 0
    buff = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * 1000));
    if(NULL == buff){
    printf("\n Unable to allocate the memory! \n");
    return -1;
}
#endif

    shmptr = shmat(shmid,0,0);
    buff = shmptr;
    //memcpy(buff,shmptr,1000);
    printf("\n %s \n",buff);

    /* Write the contents into the file */
    bytes_written = write(fd1,buff,1000);
    if(bytes_written == -1){
        printf("\n Write operation is not successfull! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Detach from the shared memory */
    shmdt(shmptr);
    //free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to copy the contents present in the shared memory to a buffer and then write the data onto a file. I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to do `buff = shmptr;`

Comment: I doubt you get a segmentation fault on that assignment. Please run in a debugger to see where it _really_ crashes.

Comment: Please note that it is useless to allocate manually the memory. The pointer retrieved using `shmat()` is directly mapped to the appropriate physical memory area (and the address is __virtual__, specific to the calling process address space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify your shmget() and your shmat() results. Probably they are returning -1 and your trying to access a invalid memory position.

Comment: @Angus, So in that case, check what `errno` contains. I suspect that your `shmget` call should look like: `shmget(key, 1000, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);` where 0644 = _"rw-r--r--"_.